# Ruby require module/class on another folder

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby and I'm trying to understand a good way to `require` modules or classes defines elsewhere. I have this setup:

```
test/
  database/
    base.rb
  scripts/
    run.rb
```

**base.rb**

```
module A
  def hi
    puts "It works"
  end
end
```

**run.rb**

```
# I don't know how to require module A here
hi()
```

Now I know I can do something like: `require "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/database/base"` but that looks fragile. I want to know if there is a way to add a folder to the `LOAD_PATH` of a particular folder or the whole application.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe the following will work:

```
require_relative '../database/base'
```

Inside `run.rb` file, `include A` and then run file

Answer (score 1):

It depends on from which file you are requiring other `ruby` file. Its relative to the host file.
In you situation

```
test/
  database/
    base.rb
  scripts/
    run.rb
```

I suppose you are tying to require the `base.rb` from `run.rb` then do this

```
require '../database/base.rb'
class SomeClass
  include A
  def some_method
    hi()
  end
end
```